# Behavior of Lambda expression with multiple statements without curly brackets

Tags: java, lambda

```
public class A  {
    interface Interface{
        void print();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface i=()->{System.out.println("1");System.out.println("2");System.out.println("3");System.out.println("4");};
        i.print();
    }
}
output:
1
2
3
4
```

when I remove  the curly brackets like this:

```
public class A  {
    interface Interface{
        void print();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface i=()->System.out.println("1");System.out.println("2");System.out.println("3");System.out.println("4");
        i.print();
    }
}
output:
2
3
4
1
```

I know we have to use curly brackets when we want to implement more than 1 statement. When we remove the curly brackets application is still compiling but my question is why second statement is executed first and first statement as last? I couldn't found any explanation about this.

Comment: Just like anywhere else in Java - semicolon indicates "end of statement".  So `Interface i=()->System.out.println("1");` is one statement; `System.out.println("2");` is executed as a separate, standalone statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Interface i=()->System.out.println("1");System.out.println("2");System.out.println("3");System.out.println("4");
i.print();
```

Most of those expressions are not part of the lambda. Java does not treat newlines as significant, so this is equivalent to

```
Interface i=()->System.out.println("1");
System.out.println("2");
System.out.println("3");
System.out.println("4");
i.print();
```

and now it's clearer what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your second code after formatting it properly:

```
public class A  {
   interface Interface{
     void print();
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Interface i=()->System.out.println("1");
      System.out.println("2");
      System.out.println("3");
      System.out.println("4");
      i.print();
   }
}
```

function `i()` is assigned to only `System.out.println("1")` since there is no braces.

So, before `i.print()`, the other statements are getting invoked i.e,

```
System.out.println("2");System.out.println("3");System.out.println("4");
```

and then `i.print()` invokes `System.out.println("1")`